# save cookies from curl auth post

Tags: unix, cookies, curl, libcurl

I am sending the following request via command line osx

```
curl -X POST "http://thing.com/feeds/auth" -d "username=name"  -d "password=password"
```

I am receiving a message as follows:

```
<authentication status="passed">
  <timestamp timeZone="EST">20140317194754</timestamp>  
</authentication>
```

I need to capture the cookie that is created when i authenticate so I can use if for further requests. How would I do this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the parameter --dump-header to save the header into a file. From there you can get the cookie. It will be beside the response header `Set-Cookie:`

```
--dump-header /var/tmp/xyz/header.txt
```